# String Interpolation in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code in scala,

```
def string_concatenation(strs: String*): String = {
  var res = ""
  for (x <- strs) {
    res += x
  }
  res
}

val strA = "Hello"
val strB = "World"
val rule1: String = "string_concatenation(strA, strB)"
val res1 = s"$rule1"
println("Result 1: " + res1)

val res2 = s"${string_concatenation(strA, strB)}"
println("Result 2: " + res2)
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
Result 1: string_concatenation(strA, strB)
Result 2: HelloWorld
```

**I need the string "rule1" to be evaluated to give "HelloWorld".**

Is there a way I can achieve this in scala (or) using spark functionalities in scala ?

I tried the following methods but of no use:

**Method 1:**

```
val res3 = s"${s"$rule1"}"
println("Result 3: " + res3)
```

**Output:**

```
Result 3: string_concatenation(strA, strB)
```

**Method 2:**

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val rule2 = q"$rule1"
val res4 = toolbox.compile(rule2)()
println("Result 4: " + res4)
```

**Output:**

```
Result 4: string_concatenation(strA, strB)
```

Comment: Ok... so now the question is why do you want to do this ? Scala is a compiled language... and although doing this is possible, it is something which should be considered only if absolutely required. So, instead of asking how to do this... you should share your actual problem statement which lead you into trying to do this.

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh,

I have some rules in a text file (similar to rule1 above) which needs to be applied on variables read in from another file (similar to strA above). This is the problem at hand. It would be helpful if you could share the possible way of achieving the result. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, the rules in your file are steps of the the program. You need to parse those steps and transform them into a AST and then evaluate that AST. By AST, I mean corresponding representation of those steps in Scala. If your steps are simple enough then you can simply define a simple AST and then an evaluator for your AST. If the rules are complex enough then you might consider a proper parser-combinator (like fastparse) or even PEG parser ( like parboiled2)

Comment: Will any other tool work which can evaluate a String expression in JVM (using scala , java)

Comment: @Sarvesh, Thank you for your suggestion. I will try that way.

Comment: @Salim, Yeah it is fine to use any other tool as well. Please mention if you have any specific tool in mind. Thank you

Comment: Yes, if you can use `spring` in your project then spring has something for expression evaluations called `Spring Expression Language`... that might be worth looking into.